# Does Postgresql varchar count using unicode character length or ASCII character length?

Tags: postgresql, unicode

I tried importing a database dump from a SQL file and the insert failed when inserting the string `Mér` into a field defined as `varying(3)`. I didn't capture the exact error, but it pointed to that specific value with the constraint of `varying(3)`.

Given that I considered this unimportant to what I was doing at the time, I just changed the value to `Mer`, it worked, and I moved on.

Is a `varying` field with its limit taking into account length of the byte string? What really boggles my mind is that this was dumped from another PostgreSQL database. So it doesn't make sense how a constraint could allow the value to be written initially.

Comment: Character encoding is a per-database thing. PostgreSQL supports all sorts of encodings, but only one can be in effect for a given database. Perhaps your source database was set up for a different encoding than the target.

Comment: Look for this text (middle of the page) in the manual. It seems to suggest that the encoding determines the number of chars required: The storage requirement for data of these types is 4 bytes plus the actual string... [with multibyte character encodings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/datatype-character.html) the number of characters and bytes can be quite different...

Comment: Upvoted Pointy's comment - would select it were it the answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The length limit imposed by `varchar(N)` types and calculated by the `length` function is in characters, not bytes. So `'abcdef'::char(3)` is truncated to `'abc'` but `'a€cdef'::char(3)` is truncated to `'a€c'`, even in the context of a database encoded as UTF-8, where `'a€c'` is encoded using 5 bytes.

If restoring a dump file complained that `'Mér'` would not go into a `varchar(3)` column, that suggests you were restoring a UTF-8 encoded dump file into a SQL_ASCII database.

For example, I did this in a UTF-8 database:

```
create schema so4249745;
create table so4249745.t(key varchar(3) primary key);
insert into so4249745.t values('Mér');
```

And then dumped this and tried to load it into a SQL_ASCII database:

```
pg_dump -f dump.sql --schema=so4249745 --table=t
createdb -E SQL_ASCII -T template0 enctest
psql -f dump.sql enctest
```

And sure enough:

```
psql:dump.sql:34: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(3)
CONTEXT:  COPY t, line 1, column key: "Mér"
```

By contrast, if I create the database enctest as encoding LATIN1 or UTF8, it loads fine.

This problem comes about because of a combination of dumping a database with a multi-byte character encoding, and trying to restore it into a SQL_ASCII database. Using SQL_ASCII basically disables the transcoding of client data to server data and assumes one byte per character, leaving it to the clients to take responsibility for using the right character map. Since the dump file contains the stored string as UTF-8, that is four bytes, so a SQL_ASCII database sees that as four characters, and therefore regards it as violating the constraint. And it prints out the value, which my terminal then reassembles as three characters.

Answer (score 5):

It depends what value you used when you created the database. `createdb -E UNICODE` creates a Unicode DB that should also accept multibyte characters and count them as one character.

You can use

```
psql -l
```

to see which encoding was used.
[This page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/multibyte.html) has a table including information about how many bytes per character are used.