# How exactly is the length of a Postgres VARCHAR determined (UTF-8)?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding

The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) is very specific that `VARCHAR(n)` refers to a type which can store strings up to `n` characters (*not* bytes) in length. What a "character" actually is depends on the selected encoding for the database ([Postgres supports lots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html)).

For the sake of simplicity here, let's assume we're working with a database with UTF-8 encoding. The question, then: If we specify a `VARCHAR(n)` type, we're allowed to store `n` "characters", as Postgres calls them, but what precisely constitutes a character, to Postgres? If we want to check, in another language, that some string will fit in a `VARCHAR(n)`, what should we actually be checking?

Unpacking this a little: First, unsurprisingly, some UTF-8 codepoints require more than 1 byte to store. For example,  requires 4 bytes, and has hex representation `0xf09f9880`. This should probably just be considered 1 character.

The complication comes when we look at single *characters* which by represented with more than one UTF-8 *codepoint*. For example  (the Antarctic flag) is comprised of two codepoints: U+1F1E6  and U+1F1F6 . When these codepoints occur sequentially, they form a single visible character, the Antarctic flag. Does Postgres consider this as 1 character, for a Varchar? Or as 2?

From some testing, it appears a Postgres UTF-8 character is a codepoint. Trying to insert  into a `VARCHAR(1)` works, trying to insert  does not. Is this how it works? Or is it more complicated?

Comment: as utf8 can have 3 or 4 bytes per character, you should be more specific

Comment: and your arctic flag would need 2 characters as your insert already proofs. for evry U+nnn 1

Comment: @nbk I would like to think I’ve been quite specific here. Is a multibyte codepoint always considered 1 character by pg (testing implies yes)? Is a single visible character consisting of multiple codepoints never considered 1 character by pg?

Comment: Obviously my test insert shows the flag is not considered a single character, but I’m looking for a specific explanation of what is considered a single character in pg (most likely the answer is a single codepoint, I’m just interested).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Postgresql varchar count using unicode character length or ASCII character length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249745/does-postgresql-varchar-count-using-unicode-character-length-or-ascii-character)

Comment: @nbk Unfortunately that doesn’t answer the question. I do know that Varchar counts characters, not bytes (or equivalently ASCII character length). The question is what definition of a UTF-8 “character” Postgres actually uses when counting, since that is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `length()` or, equivalently, the `char_length()` function to measure the length of a string. These function count the number of code points in the string, and that is also what is delimited by the type modifier of `character varying`. PostgreSQL counts the length of a combining character as the number of code points involved.